# Conflict between Wordpress Slideshow and Magnific slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, magnific-popup

I am loading a Wordpress Slideshow (using default gallery and shortcode from Jetpack) inside a magnific popup. The directional arrows for the magnific slideshow are conflicting with the directional arrows of the wordpress slideshow.

I can scroll through the Wordpress slideshow fine.

I find the magnific slideshow nav sometimes does not work - it sometimes scrolls through the wordpress images / only scrolls to the next magnific item once the wordpress slideshow is at the end.

Any ideas on how to let these nav's target their own only.

Thanks

Pastebin of Generated Code: http://pastebin.com/gTQzd0tm
Screenshot to illustrate: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x8p2vdygwmprbm6/Screenshot%202014-06-20%2009.00.31.png

n.b screenshot - the left arrow is the nav arrow for the magnific popup. The two arrows and pause button are from the Wordpress slideshow.

Comment: Can you show some of the rendered code? Maybe changing selectors would help.

Comment: Hi @isherwood - I've added a pastebin of code and a screenshot - thanks for looking.